# Saving geotiff map in Hector_slam

Tags: hector-slam, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS. I have been trying to save my lidar data as a geotiff map using Hector _Slam . The tutorial says to run :

```
rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"
```

Running this command does not show any error. The tutorial says that it will then automatically save the map to  the 'hector_slam/hector_geotiff/maps' folder . However I find no hector_geotiff folder within the Hector_SLAM folder. I was wondering if I need to create some listener node for this purpose. Please guide as I am a beginner in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209730/saving-geotiff-map-in-hector_slam/) by [Raman](https://answers.ros.org/users/21878/raman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2015-05-28**:
Please check logs of hector_geotiff node. Also, could you please share your output for rostopic list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to run this command to save the map either while the mapping process is ongoing (then you will get a partial map) or once you are satisfied by the produced map as shown by RVIZ (then you will get a full map).

Note that hector_slam should be active for hector_map_server to be able to export the generated map.

Please refer to this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData for detailed steps.

hector_slam package has hector_geotiff with a folder called "maps".

Download hector_slam full version from: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.
catkin_make it and run:

```
roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch
```

with

```
rosbag play Team_Hector_MappingBox_RoboCup_2011_Rescue_Arena.bag  --clock
```

as described in the mentioned tutorial, then save the map using:

```
rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"
```

---

Originally posted by [samer.hanoun](https://answers.ros.org/users/23742/samer.hanoun/) with karma: 56 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed hector_slam via apt-get, so the package is on /opt/ros/DISTRO/share path (mine was indigo). In this case, I've had to recursively change hector_geotiff's folder owner because savegeotiff command had no permission to generate *.tif and *.tfw files. Another issue was referred maps folder missing on my installation, so I've had to manually create it.

So if you:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-hector-slam
```

then:

```
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP /opt/ros/DISTRO/share/hector_geotiff
```

If maps folder is missing:

```
mkdir /opt/ros/DISTRO/share/hector_geotiff/maps
```

Run again (while hector_slam launch and bag are running too):

```
rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"
```

---

Originally posted by [rebecatourinho](https://answers.ros.org/users/36538/rebecatourinho/) with karma: 31 on 2018-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) on 2018-11-07**:
Hi I am unable to execute the second command. Error is invalid user: "USER:GROUP". How can I solve this?

**Comment by [rebecatourinho](https://answers.ros.org/users/36538/rebecatourinho/) on 2018-11-12**:
You need to replace USER by your username and GROUP by a group you belong to. Generally, are the same, like *username:username*.